# Is the Rogue POTUS Staff Twitter account an actual POTUS Staffer?

Tags: united-states, politics, twitter

I have seen talk floating around regarding a twitter account claiming to be members of the white house staff.

https://twitter.com/roguepotusstaff

The account has all the *appearence* of legitimacy, but such a thing is obviously hard to believe and not hard to fake.

Is there any reason to believe that this account is run by a member of the POTUS Staff or someone in an official capacity in the White House?

Comment: FWIW: http://joshleitzel.com/2017/02/06/rogue-potus-staff/